# How to verify that Googlebot can access the URL of a video thumbnail?

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, video, url-inspection-tool

I need to check if Googlebot can see my image thumbnails. When I use the URL Inspection Tool, Google cannot see my images in the page.  In the rendered screen shot, it displays a black box instead of thumbnails.

Also my thumbnails dropped in SERP.

This is a sample URL:

```
https://tamasha.com/v/7xGLB
```

And this is my thumbnail:

```
https://s-v2.tamasha.com/statics/images/posters/b9/78/7xGLB_b978d6931ce8020a940b3bffd3eeb1e2e7b76bb4_2094x1185.jpg?w=800
```

I need to check if Googlebot has access to the above URLs.

Note that *robots.txt* is OK and I checked the [verifying Googlebbot page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553) but it doesn't seem to be helpful for this situation.

Comment: When you say  that your thumbnails dropped in the search results, are you talking about Google image search?  Your thumbnails are not ranking as well in Google image search anymore?   I ask because Google wouldn't usually index images in web search, and even in image search Google prefers to index full sized images rather than thumbnails.   Why do you need to have  video thumbnails ranking anyway?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No. I'm talking about "All" tab SERP. Not even videos.
Its Greatly related to ranking. When you have not image thumbnail in SERP, You will lost CTR and Your clicks decreased.

2 Month ago our thumbnails dropped.And Now we have half of traffic of 2 month ago

But my question is just about dropping thumbnails of video in SERP. Not about ranking or image or video search.